# vue-multiselect sort selected

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.4, multi-select

Is there any way to have the selected items using vue-mulitiselect in vuejs and Laravel5.4 sorted by value. For example if I choose “node2” first than choose “node1” I want it to auto order/sort them like “node1 node2”.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Doing so seems less intuitive than the normal behavior.

If you are working with a large list and need it value sorted, you could use a single select list and add it to a list (like above the input field) on input. I find most users get confused by these big multi-selects after 5+ items and its better to put it into a more readable list.

Comment: The list is a list of servers that get built out after submission. The order is always that the smallest numbered server is the master server and has different steps in the build process. I can sort on the server side and the user doesn't even notice, its more for displaying what is actually happening on the end. They need to be able to select as many servers they need for the given project as well. They don't always selected by order when in a hurry, its more cosmetic than anything.

Comment: I don't think vue-multiselect supports that. You could modify it to use a computed property instead of internalValue.

Or you could use http://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/ and use the .sync modifier to sync with data on the parent component. You can then use a watcher to see if it changes and if so then sort the array however you'd like.  I personally would probably use a custom list to display what has been chosen and only use a single select to add to that list.

Comment: I was able to achieve what I need by adding a watch event, each time it changed/selected a new option it just sorted the value associated to the v-model.

Comment: @debow could you share your code please! That is that I need